# Is there an F# equivalent of Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty?

Tags: linq, f#

After searching quite a bit, I couldn't find an F# equivalent of [Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx).

Does something similar exists in F# (perhaps in a different, idiomatic, way)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Seq` module functions operate and return `IEnumerable<_>`'s and `DefaultIfEmpty` operate and return `IEnumerable<_>`'s. How about just wrap it in function that is composable.

```
let inline DefaultIfEmpty d l = System.Linq.Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty(l, d)
```

This also preserves laziness.

*example:*

```
Seq.empty |> DefaultIfEmpty 0
```

**Update**

I've made an open source library inlining many extension and static methods, including `Enumerable.defaultIfEmpty` -- [ComposableExtesions](http://jay.tuley.name/ComposableExtensions/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I ended up using this code as it's compact, the method is accessible by default and I can use it without 'open'ing the System.Linq namespace. Furthermore, I trust that the BCL's `DefaultIfEmpty` implementation is tested against (most/all) possible scenarios. Using a function as a decorator looks like a good technique (and I think it's quite idiomatic as well). Once again, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Given that this is simply a wrapper, I think it would be wise to mark it as inline.

Answer (score 6):

To preserve the laziness of the sequence, we could work with the enumerator's state.

```
let DefaultIfEmpty (l:'t seq) (d:'t) = 
    seq{
        use en = l.GetEnumerator()
        if en.MoveNext() then 
            yield en.Current
            while en.MoveNext() do
                yield en.Current 
        else
            yield d }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `use` needs to be inside the `seq { }` block - otherwise the enumerator is created eagerly and disposed too soon.

Comment: @kvb So much for the beam in my own eye. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The provided code works. However, since Stack Overflow allows me to choose only 1 correct answer I had to pick the one I ended up using. Once again, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

There are a few options:

1. Use `DefaultIfEmpty` which might be non-idiomatic  but will work
2. write your own like so:

   ```
   let DefaultIfEmpty (l:'t seq) (d:'t) = 
       match Seq.length l with |0 -> seq [d] |_ -> l
   ```
3. Worry about infinite sequences

   ```
   let DefaultIfEmpty (l:'t seq) (d:'t) = 
       match Seq.isEmpty l with |true -> seq [d] |false -> l
   ```

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to use `Seq.length` for this - what if you're given an infinite sequence as input?

Comment: @kvb - fixed with an extra example

Comment: @John Palmer - Sorry. Your #3 evaluates the first element twice.

Comment: Your last version seems the most readable and idiomatic. One nitpick: `if`/`else` seems a bitter fit than `match`/`with` here.

Comment: Oops. Should have been _better_.

Comment: To elaborate on my comment: Consider `let foo = Seq.unfold (fun x -> printf "%d," x; Some (x, x + 1)) 0 in DefaultIfEmpty foo -1`, which prints _0,0,1,2,3,..._. Looks like when `Seq.isEmpty` disposes the enumerator, `Seq.unfold` restarts the generator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The provided code works. Regarding the issue with infinite sequences, there are [many other methods suffering from the same symptom](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/07/20/linq-versus-the-lsp/) so I think this implementation shouldn't be blamed for. However, since Stack Overflow allows me to choose only 1 correct answer I had to pick the one I ended up using. Once again, thank you for your answer!